# Drop down always comes below the visible area - Combobox Autocomplete jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working with combobox autocomplete (jqueryui).  Drop down always comes below the visible area so cant see the list names at all. So please how to change the selector position of the drop down list so that i can see all the list names.

ref link: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

[image]

This is the snapshot in the right down corner. When i click on show all items arrow mark it comes below the visible area where i cant see the all item list.

Comment: This one might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549860/im-having-trouble-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete-and-slider-on-the-same-form-z-in